# Customizing Tabgroup icons in active/inactive state

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

How to change the icon of the tab while tab is in active state ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this using

```
Ti.UI.currentTab.icon = 'icon_image.png';
```

Also refer to this [link](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/135063/how-to-change-active-tab-icon). Hope it will help.